# Real Name appearing under user information

Tags: support, username, facebook

I registered with my facebook account (doesn't seem like the best idea now) a while ago. I noticed that my real name appears in my account information. I tried removing it, but it keeps appearing again, any way to permanently remove it? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Real Name" field in your profile is only visible to you, moderators and Stack Exchange employees. If you log out and look at your profile it's not there.

You will need to click **Save Profile** button when making a change on your profile to keep the update.

Your meta profile here will be updated in due time as that pulls from the main site profile information.

Testing the edit, removed it for you in this case to see it go.